# Count documents with given field value problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, callback, robo3t

I have one problem regarding return value of count function of `db.collection.find.count()`; namely my program should return integer value (number of documents in `db.collection` by certain criteria), but function returns `Promise` which I don't know how to use in callback function.

I tried to make callback function inside `count()` method like `count(function(err,res){ if(err) console.log('Error') else count1=res;})`,but it doesnt work. i also searched stackoverflow and mongodb documentation, and tried some other solutions but it didn't help also. (but when i tried `db.collection('blogCollection').find("author":"user123").count()` in robomongo, it correctly ran and displayed result of query)

This is my code `var count1=database.collection("blogCollection").find({"author":id}).count();`

where `count1` should be the number of documents where `author` field equals to `id` value. Thank you in advance for helping.:) My mongodb is 3.2 version, and node is v10.15.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promises and callbacks have different syntaxes. You can check how `Promise` works [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). You may also want to check the difference with callbacks [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539815/arent-promises-just-callbacks).

In your case, you can use a `Promise` like here:

```
database.collection("blogCollection").find({"author":id}).count()
  .then((count1) => {
    console.log(count1);
});
```

You can also opt to use ES6 [Async/Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```
async function count() {
  const count1 = await database.collection("blogCollection").find({"author":id}).count();
  console.log(count1);
}
```

Note the `async` before the `function`, and the `await` before calling the database function.

Answer (score 0):

theres should be multiple callbacks within your code not just at the end

refer to this [Callback at MongoDB Operation With Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743564/callback-at-mongodb-operation-with-node-js)

as well as the count function for the node driver doesnt need to operate on a cursor http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#count

so your code should really look like

```
database.collection("blogCollection", (err, col) => {
    col.count(query,opt,  (err,count )=> count1 = count)
)
```

with async await

```
const col = await database.collection("blogColelction")
const count1 = await col.count(query, opt)
```